# Redis causing issue with AMQP

Tags: magento2, redis, rabbit-mq

We are developing a new site and have created some custom consumers for AMQP, however we are getting the error `Error while checking if topic is synchronous` during the setup:upgrade part of our deployment process.

I have identified that it looks to be redis causing this as removing the redis block from the env.php file resolves this. But I am not sure where to go after this.

Comment: double check the configuration of your queue topics. Are your topics sync or aysnc? Have you checked your log files for further information?

Comment: Did you ever find out why?